# Haskell. Non IO Exception handling

Tags: haskell, exception

I am trying to catch exception due to with the action ([1,2] !! 3). I can not.

I was trying

```
let a = [1,2]
```

- `handle  (\(e :: SomeException) -> print "err" >> return 1) (return $ a !! 3)`
- `Control.Exception.catch (return $ a !! 3) (\(e::SomeException) -> print "err" >> return 1)`

in both i get  Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large*

Is it possible? Probably i am to use Maybe approach.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laziness and exceptions, like laziness and parallelism, interact in subtle ways!

The `return` wraps up your array access in a thunk, so that it is returned unevaluated, causing the exception to be evaluated outside of the handler.

The solution is to ensure that evaluating `return` must also evaluate the list index. This can be done via `$!` in this case:

> handle ((e :: SomeException) -> print "err" >> return 1) (return $! a !! 3)

Comment: "evaluating `return` must also evaluate the list index" -- this is good phrasing for thinking about strictness.  +1

Comment: sometimes i forget about the haskell laziness

Answer (score 4):

This usually means your code is too lazy and the dereference happens after the handler returns.  Try using `$!` instead of `$` to force evaluation.